# Pom file not reading environment variables

Tags: java, maven, ant

UPDATE:

If I change ${env.JAVA_HOME} to a system property ${java.home} then it executes the *maven-dependency-plugin unpack* and *copy* tasks. But now it fails on the *maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:run (build-content).*

```
[ERROR] one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact ... at specified path ... -> [Help 1]
```

Why is it looking for my jar files in the JRE folder?

```
/{path to jdk}/Contents/Home/jre/lib/...
```

It's sitting right here:

```
/{path to jdk}/Contents/Home/lib
```

My pom.xml file is not reading my JAVA_HOME environment variable. I'm on a Mac. Here's the entry:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>{groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>{artifactId}</artifactId>
        <version>${version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/myPersonalJar.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here's the error:

```
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] 'build.plugins.plugin[org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin].dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for ... must specify an absolute path but is ${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/myPersonalJar.jar
```

In the iTerm app I can echo $JAVA_HOME and it points to the right place.

It works just fine when I hardcode the *systemPath* to my Java home. I can't figure out why. To give some context, my ant build files aren't reading my environment variables either.

Am I missing something stupid simple?

Comment: Of course, JAVA_HOME is explicitly set in your environment?  Which Java release/distro are you using?  Many have the JRE as a subdirectory to the JDK.  So, it looks like your JAVA_HOME is being set to /{path to jdk}/Contents/Home/jre instead of /{path to jdk}/Contents/Home.

Comment: the jre is a subdirectory of the jdk. and JAVA_HOME is showing correctly as: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home. But it's not failing initially like it did before. It gets past the initial error starts to add the dependencies and then it fails. Seems like a dependency is causing this issue.

Comment: yup, your updated edit shows Maven is looking for tools.jar in 1.7 but your JAVA_HOME is 1.8 (and under the jre subdirectory).  I'll post the profile I used to add the dependency for both builds and antrun.

Comment: Interesting. If I look in the project specific settings --> java compiler, the compliance level is 1.7. Is that what is causing this?

Comment: There is definitely something awry plus antrun is finicky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this profile to your `pom.xml` (in `<profiles/>`):

```xml
<profile>
  <id>tools.jar</id>
  <activation>
    <file><exists>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</exists></file>
  </activation>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>jdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>${java.specification.version}</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>jdk</groupId>
              <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
              <version>${java.specification.version}</version>
              <scope>system</scope>
              <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
            <docletPath>${tools.jar}</docletPath>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</profile>
```

I've included the corresponding change to the javadoc plug-in which may or
may not be useful to you.  You can remove it if you don't need it.

Comment: Yeah, it's still not working. It is throwing a warning before the unpack task. It's still looking in the JRE folder and I don't know why: 'build.plugins.plugin[org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin].dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.sun:tools:jar refers to a non-existing file /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/tools.jar

Comment: Did you remove your `com.sun:tools` dependency after adding the profile?

Comment: You're right, that does work. But why? Now it gets stuck when it tries to load Apache Ivy: [echo] ivy.home is ${env.USERPROFILE}/ivy. Another environment variable issue. There's got to be something larger going on.

Comment: The mvn environment variables are not being propagated to the ant invocation.  You need a strategy to propagate those values through properties.  If your ant tasks are expressed in a build.xml then you can look at using the [Maven Artifact Resolver Ant Tasks](https://maven.apache.org/resolver-ant-tasks/) to access the POM's properties.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help. I'll check it out.

Comment: I think I see the original issue in this warning that I hadn't noticed before: objc[41000]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (0x100b9c4c0) and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib (0x100bef4e0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.